# WCF Data Service HTML

Tags: html, wcf

I want to create a mechanism to allow users to embed a simple list (using UL and LI) of their publications in their own webpages.

The source of the data is a SSRS database so I was thinking about using a WCF Data Service.  But I see that the WCF data Service only returns ATOM or JSON data.

Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Some of my recent projects have been using a WCF Web Service to populate html drop downs without any problems. In our case we have been setting the return types to lists of strings (VB.net) and using javascript to read the return (appears as an array) to create new options for the drop down. It is possible no doubt, but expecting a user to know enough javascript to make the web service call and populate the list might be a bit much. If you are supplying that code as well I don't think there would be any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the returned JSON data and use MustacheJs or any other javascript templating tool to display the data as UL and Li

The below code i have used web api which is a simple form of wcf data services. you can use anything which returns a JSON dat.

**Mustache Template**

```
<script id="RoleTemplate" type="Mustache/html">
  {{ #roles }}
         <UL>
              <Li>{{RoleID}} - {{RoleName}} ({{Description}}) </Li>
         </UL>    
{{ /roles }}
```

**Web api controller code**

```
   public class SecurityController : ApiController
{


    // GET api/<controller>
    /// <summary>
    /// Get all role details
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Role> GetAllRoles()
    {
        myApp.Security.Services.ISecurityService objSecurity = new myApp.Security.Services.SecurityService();
        return objSecurity.GetAllRole();
    }
}
```

**Ajax call**

```
     function getAllRoles() {
         $.ajax({
             dataType: "json",
             url: '/api/Security/GetAllRole',
             success: function (data) {
                 data = { 'roles': data }; // formatting the data to support the mustache format 
                 var html = Mustache.to_html($('#RoleTemplate').html(), data);
                 $('#tblRole').append(html);


             }
         });
```